# I can't configure subplots or see the title set

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/kylerbrown/29ce940165b22b8f25f4) code for different and inverted axes online and I was running it with mostly great results. However, I ran into this strange problem. I can't configure the subplots - either on the output screen or via `subplots_adjust`. I have set a title as well but it doesn't display on top. I sent it to a friend online and the weird bit is that it works perfectly well on his machine.

Where am I going wrong? Is it my machine?
[image: Screenshot of my code - without the title]

[image: Peter McCeever's output on his machine]

Comment: Could you provide some example code?

Comment: I included a hyperlink to github in the first sentence itself. That's pretty much the exact code I'm using